# How to retrieve data from columns dependent upon date

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a rota (a fixed order of rotation (as of persons or duties)) that I've already had help with this week. It's up & running as is, but for simpler reading I'd like to transpose it.

You can see the transposed sheet as I'd like it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hRX0e_S_kp_yA1kuRXzReqG0ak9xUVdMcTZHMoo1X0k/edit?usp=sharing)

The current script is for the pre-transposed table.

It would search Column 0 for the date. If it was was 7 days away it would retrieve the name from Column 1 & match it with e-mail address in separate sheet etc.

What I'd like to do is instead have the Date in Row 0 & then subsequent names in Row 1 etc etc

I've tried various things. I've stepped through the code & can see what it's doing, & I've done some reading through about 2 dimensional arrays, but I can't seem to find a way of getting the code to work down through columns, instead of across the rows.

Here's the code:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Rota")
  ss1.setActiveSheet(sh1);
  var rotalink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LgzUWSAGA2kbpar8r5nosU1bSHF7nrtvtUiHS3nB_e8";
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Fetch the range
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B3:G50")
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data)  {
    var row = data[i];
    var today=new Date();
    var timecell = new Date(row[0]);
    var timediff = new Date();
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
    var daystogo = Math.ceil((timecell.getTime()-today.getTime())/(one_day));
    if (daystogo==7) {//only e-mail people with one week to go. To change that alter the "7" to the number of days you want
        var subject = "Rota reminder!";
        var emailAddress = [];
        var message;
        message = "Hello \n\n"+
                 "You are down to help at Youth Café this week. \n\n" +

                  "Please see the below rota for your role \n\n" +

                  "If you have any questions or problems let us know at thameyouthcafe@gmail.com \n\n" +

                   "Remember, you can check the rota anytime by clicking on the link below: \n\n"+ 

                  rotalink



for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) { // 5 because emails are till col4
  //  var emailAddress = []; // Start by collecting the non-blank emails in an array
    if (getEmailFromName(row[x]) != "") {
      emailAddress.push(getEmailFromName(row[x]))
    }
  }
  emailAddress = emailAddress.join();  // Join the array to get a comma separated string
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the getEmailFromName function that matches with SKey (which I presume comes from the "i" variable in the first function?

```
function getEmailFromName(sKey) {



  // to use this function, don’t put anything in the first column (A) or row (1).

  // Put the name (i.e. the key, or what we’re looking for) in column B.

  // Put what we want to return in column C. 



  var columnToSearch = 1; //column B



  // Set the active sheet to our email lookup

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("EmailContactList")

  ss1.setActiveSheet(sh1);



  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  var line = -1;

  for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {

    if( data[i][columnToSearch] == sKey ) {

      line = i;

      break;

    }

  }



  if( line != -1 ) {

    //do what you want with the data on "line"

    return data[line][2]; //value on column C of the matched line

  } 

  else {

    return "";

  // if criteria is not found

 }

}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your goal, can you add the result you want to your shared Spreadsheet?

Comment: Apologies, been off work. Don't know if I can - I don't want any change in data layout. 

What I want is code that will look at Row 3 on the spreadsheet - work out which date fits the criteria & then send an e-mail to the relevant names in that week dependant upon matching their names with the other sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it - thank you for your contributions. Turned out it was incredibly simple.

Just had to change this line:

```
var timecell = new Date(data[0])
```

to this:

```
var timecell = new Date(data[0][i])
```

so it iterates through the first row of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Rota")
  ss1.setActiveSheet(sh1);
  var rotalink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LgzUWSAGA2kbpar8r5nosU1bSHF7nrtvtUiHS3nB_e8";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B3:G50")
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<dataRange.length;i++)  {
    var row = data[i];
    var today=new Date();
    var timecell = new Date(row[0]);
    var timediff = new Date();
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
    var daystogo = Math.ceil((timecell.getTime()-today.getTime())/(one_day));
    if (daystogo==7) {
      var subject = "Rota reminder!";
      var emailAddress = []; 
      var message = Utilities.formatString('Hello\n\nYou are down to help at Youth Café this week.\n\n Please see the below rota for your role \n\nIf you have any questions or problems let us know at thameyouthcafe@gmail.com \n\nRemember, you can check the rota anytime by clicking on the link below: \n\n%s',rotalink);
      for (var x=1;x<5;x++) { 
        if(data[i][x]) {
          emailAddress.push(data[i][x]);
        }
      }
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress.join(), subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi
Apologies - have been away for a few days. Thank you for your response..

I've inputted that code & amended the final few rows to add in the send e-mail function. Also had to add a line:

`var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActivesheet();`

before the dataRange variable as it sheet was not identified.

Unfortunately there is no result from debugging but equally it doesn't appear to be doing anything either.

If I look at the Execution Transcript the final thing it seems to do is Range.getValues. Then finishes with Execution succeeded.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you need to single step through the program and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Tried a step through. It stops at getting data range. Something about the for statement is throwing it off. Will go back to it in the morning.